# Перенос базы данных

Tags: mysql, база-данных, postgresql

у меня задача, нужно перенести базу данных mysql в таблицу 'archives' в базе данных postgresql. У меня есть дамп базы данных mysql под названием news_dump.sql, база данных очень большая.

Comment: Установить MySQL соотв. версии. Развернуть дамп. Выгрузить данные в CSV. Импортировать в PostgreSQL.

Comment: *нужно перенести **базу** данных mysql **в таблицу** 'archives'* - нет ли тут косяка в формулировках и терминах?